# HomeController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html even though it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud

[Link to a new github repository where i generated all of the code and am still unable to render any views](https://github.com/zach28attack/test_app.git)

Comment: NO TEMPLATE FOR INTERACTIVE REQUEST                    
HomeController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html           NOTE!
Unless told otherwise, Rails expects an action to render a template with the same name,
contained in a folder named after its controller. If this controller is an API responding with 204 (No Content),
which does not require a template, then this error will occur when trying to access it via browser,
since we expect an HTML template to be rendered for such requests. If that's the case, carry on.

Comment: Have you checked your routes? rails routes

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get 'home/index'
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
end

Comment: i.m not seeing any errors in VsCode. I wonder if i'm just missing something super minor..

Comment: Could you post the error stack trace?

Comment: How would I find that exactly? Also thank you all for your help i’ve been really struggling with this on my own

Comment: I get "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated." in the debug console when i run the debugger and go to localhost:3000/home/index

Comment: Seems that means nothing in itself.

Comment: I added the dev log inside of the main post

Comment: I have replicated this basic application with all the same versions and I'm unable to produce the error, did you manually create this controller and index file or did you use the generator?

Comment: I used the generator    Rails g controller home index

Comment: I have just generated a new app and the same issue persists. i have added a link to the repo for this new app. please check that for any files that may be required but aren't being generated. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t use Windows Powershell or Git-Bash on Windows if you’re having this problem. Someone suggested on a similar post that the OP on that post should use the integrated terminal and not git-bash because it wasn’t compatible with VSCode. I tried the integrated terminal in VSCode and everything works as it should.

Thank you all for your help.